# Getting a Cannot read property of undefined, while expecting to be normal

Tags: javascript

**Question:**

Sorry if I cant summarize the problem in a nut shell, so I try to explain it in details. I try to construct a object by using a input. However there is a error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

And I a seeking for a better solution to write it in a clear way as well.

**Problem:**

```
[
  {
    id: "2197",
    name: "AC",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Equity",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },

  {
    id: "2194",
    name: "Japanese",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Equity",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },

  {
    id: "2221237",
    name: "Global Credit",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "FixedIncome",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "7123928",
    name: "Duration Bonds",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "FixedIncome",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "1121350",
    name: "Euro Cash",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Others",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
]
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  Equity: [
    { Name: "Japanese", IlliquidYears: 1.0, Turnover: 0.15 },
    { Name: "AC", IlliquidYears: 1.0, Turnover: 0.15 },
...
  ];
  FixedIncome: [
    { Name: "Global Credi", IlliquidYears: 1.0, Turnover: 0.15 },
    { Name: "Duration Bonds", IlliquidYears: 1.0, Turnover: 0.15 },
...
  ];
  Others: [{ Name: "Euro Cash", IlliquidYears: 1.0, Turnover: 0.15 }],
...
}
```

**Below is my present code:**

```
const a = [
  {
    id: "2197",
    name: "AC",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Equity",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },

  {
    id: "2194",
    name: "Japanese",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Equity",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },

  {
    id: "2221237",
    name: "Global Credit",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "FixedIncome",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "7123928",
    name: "Duration Bonds",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "FixedIncome",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "1151230",
    name: "Euro Cash",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "FixedIncome",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "1151230",
    name: "Euro Cash",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Alternatives",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "`231150",
    name: "Euro Cash",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Alternatives",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
  {
    id: "11`21350",
    name: "Euro Cash",
    currency: "EUR",
    category: "Others",
    illiquidYears: 1.0,
    turnover: 0.15,
  },
];

const trans = (a) => {
  const result = a.reduce((pre, cur) => {
    if (pre.cur.category) {
      pre.cur.category = [
        ...pre.cur.category,
        { name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears },
      ];
    } else {
      pre.cur.category = [{ name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears }];
    }

    return pre;
  }, {});

  return result;
};

const b = trans(a);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: You have to define the reduce accum props ``}, {cur:{})`` or add ``if (pre.cur?.category)`` to the condition

Comment: why do complier say cur maybe undefine while it is clearly not?

Comment: I added cur?. , and it said SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const groupByCategory = a.reduce((group, obj) => {
  const { category } = obj;
  group[category] = group[category] ?? [];
  group[category].push(obj);
  return group;
}, {});
console.log(groupByCategory);
```

Comment: This might result in for your Expected Output.

Comment: can you explain group[category] ?? []; ?

Comment: When the loop starts in reduce function the first object group is empty object with no keys on first iteration the category key is created and initializes as the empty array group[category] = group[category] ?? []; This statement ?? (Nullish coalescing operator)  initializes as the empty array if its Null else the list values.

Comment: Did you get the expected Output ?

Comment: Yes, I got the answer, may I also ask , instead of using push, do you think this way of writing push is good?  pre.cur.category = [
          ...pre.cur.category,
          { name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears },
        ];

Comment: with push you are appending to the existing array, with spread operator you are creating a copy and assigning back pre.cur.category = [ ...pre.cur.category, { name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears }. In push method you can also do like this group[category].push({ name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears }).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two examples i mentioned on the comments:

1:

```
  const trans = (a) => {
    const result = a.reduce((pre, cur) => {
      if (pre.cur.category) {
        pre.cur.category = [
          ...pre.cur.category,
          { name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears },
        ];
      } else {
        pre.cur.category = [{ name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears }];
      }
  
      return pre;
    }, {cur:{}});
  
    return result;
  };
  
  const b = trans(a);
```

2:

```
  const trans = (a) => {
    const result = a.reduce((pre, cur) => {
      if (pre.cur?.category) {
        pre.cur.category = [
          ...pre.cur.category,
          { name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears },
        ];
      } else {
        pre.cur = {}
        pre.cur.category = [{ name: cur.name, illiquidYears: cur.illiquidYears }];
      }
  
      return pre;
    }, {});
  
    return result;
  };
  
  const b = trans(a);
```

Comment: but the example code 2 got a error :if (pre.cur?.category) {

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: It works on codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/fragrant-frog-hsf6x0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark